# Update with set variable

Tags: plsql, sql-update

Hello I want to make an update from a variable in plsql but I dont know how it work:

```
  PROCEDURE MakeUpdate(row VARCHAR2,value VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
   UPDATE table
SET  row = value
```

but when I do like this , I got error that "row" do not exist in table.

Thanks !

Comment: What is the structure of our table? Do you have a column named `row`?

Comment: That is an invalid procedure definition to begin with. The `update` statement needs to be ended with a `;` and the whole procedure is missing an `end;`

Comment: @Aleksej No I dont have , I want to make procedure to update dynamic row, if I want update column row or column XXX I used the same procedure

Comment: That's not that clear to me. Do you want a generic procedure that can update whatever column in your table, based on some parameter? Also, do you have a PK in your table or any other way to identify the row(s) you want ro update?

Comment: @Aleksej "Do you want a generic procedure that can update whatever column in your table, based on some parameter?" Yes ! Exactly what's I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL, this can be a way:

```
SQL> create table tabUpdate(id number, c1 varchar2(16), c2 varchar2(16))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into tabUPdate values (1, 'COL_1', 'COL2');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tabUpdate;

        ID C1               C2
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 COL_1            COL2

SQL> create or replace procedure genUpdate(id IN number, col IN varchar2, newVal IN varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'update tabUpdate set ' || col || ' = :1 where ID = :2'
  4      using newVal, id;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec genUpdate(1, 'C1', 'NEW_COL_1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tabUPdate;

        ID C1               C2
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 NEW_COL_1        COL2

SQL>
```

Here I assume that you have a PK on your table; if not, you may need to edit the procedure to use the right conditions for your update.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have given table name and column name not the keywords "TABLE" & "ROW" otherwise you will get error because there will not be any column called "ROW", you have to appropriate table name and column name.

And when you update table it is always better to have where condition, otherwise it will update all the records.